# blank activity not visible in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have installed `Android Studio` in mac. When I create a new project, under `add and activity`, I am unable to view `Blank Activity`. Please view the attachment for screenshot.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCeOy.png)

Is this default activity not available in version 2.0 ?

Comment: empty Activity Is blank activity.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. How do I replicate blank activity with fragment ?

Comment: there is 2 -3 way to replicate blank activity with fragment refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html